# `replaceState` not working inside `then` of a Promise

Tags: authentication, reactjs, react-router, flux, history.js

Let's assume that we have an API call authenticates the user and then based on if a user is returned from the server or not, we either replaceState or do nothing, which might look something like this:

`<Route component={App} onEnter={authUser} />`

```
const onEnter = (nextState, replaceState) => {
  if (isClient) {
    AuthHelper.findCurrentUser()
      .then(response => {
        // This here doesn't work, `replaceState` doesn't change the page or URL, however I know for sure
        // that the line is being called because if I put a `debugger` right before it,
        // the `debugger` hits every time...
        replaceState({nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}, '/dashboard');
      })
      .catch(response => {});

    // If we put the same line here, it redirects the user to the dashbaord.
    // replaceState({nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}, '/dashboard');
  }
}
```

The only differentiating factor between replaceState working and not working is that one is called from within the then of a Promise, and one is called outside of the Promise resolution. Does the Promise affect replaceState from executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for asynchronous `onEnter` hooks is necessarily a bit difference, since we need a way to block the transition until the handler has completed running.

If your `onEnter` hook is asynchronous, then it needs to take a 3rd argument, e.g.

```js
function onEnter(nextState, replaceState, callback) {
    /* ... */
}
```

When you do this, you have to call `callback()` yourself when your enter hook has finished running. It's necessary for us to use this API to support people who e.g. aren't using

Comment: DOH. Thank you so much good sir :) However I must say it wasn't in the React Router docs so I was left very confused....

Comment: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replacestate-callback